# jquery: script runs only when run chunk by chunk in console but not the whole thing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing some cleaning up of an html page by removing anchor and just leaving the text node, wrapping all the text nodes (no elements surrounding it) with the tag `<asdf>`, remove all empty elements like `<div></div>` or `<span> </span>`.

When I try it on different websites, it seems to have different levels of success when I copy paste the entire script. However, when I run it chunk by chunk, it works as expected and no error is thrown.

```
//remove anchors but text intact
$('a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $.text([this]);
});

//wrap text nodes
var items = window.document.getElementsByTagName("*"); for (var i = items.length; i--;) { wrap(items[i]) }; function wrap(el){ var oDiv = el; for (var i = 0; i < oDiv.childNodes.length; i++) { var curNode = oDiv.childNodes[i]; if (curNode.nodeName === "#text" && oDiv.childNodes.length !== 1) { var firstText = curNode; var newNode = document.createElement("asdf"); newNode.textContent = firstText.nodeValue; firstText.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, firstText); } } }

//remove empty elements
$("*").filter(function () {
    return !($.trim($(this).text()).length);
}).hide();
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === '' && $(this).children().length == 0
}).remove()
```

It throws an error like

`NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`

this is caused by:

```
$('a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $.text([this]);
});
```

so maybe if I fix that, it will work.

Comment: likely have better results pulling the html from DOM, do wrapping outside of DOM...then replace all the html at one time

Answer (score 1):

Did you test the script by having it written all in one line:

```
$('a').replaceWith(function() { return document.createTextNode($.text([this]));}); var items = window.document.getElementsByTagName("*"); for (var i = items.length; i--;) { wrap(items[i]) }; function wrap(el){ var oDiv = el; for (var i = 0; i < oDiv.childNodes.length; i++) { var curNode = oDiv.childNodes[i]; if (curNode.nodeName === "#text" && oDiv.childNodes.length !== 1) { var firstText = curNode; var newNode = document.createElement("asdf"); newNode.textContent = firstText.nodeValue; firstText.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, firstText); } } };$("*").filter(function () { return !($.trim($(this).text()).length);}).hide();$('*').filter(function() { return $.trim($(this).text()) === '' && $(this).children().length == 0;}).remove();
```

On Chrome it worked everywhere I tested and jQuery was present.

Comment: I am getting an error like this `NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`

Comment: I found that this code is causing the error `$('a').replaceWith(function() {return $.text([this]);});`

Comment: Have to ask again: in the pages that you test are you sure jQuery lib is loaded?

Comment: Check to see if with my recent edit you get what you want. (changed the replaceWith callback to return: `return document.createTextNode($.text([this]));`)

Comment: if you need to include jquery you can use this: `var f = document.createElement('script');
f.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
f.setAttribute("src", '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);`